# Find out how many times function is used in database

Tags: sql-server

I had this function that was checking if some specific day is off day or not but it was not serving purpose well so I find out another way to check the day and it is working more efficiently than the function. I don't remember at how many places or in how many procedures/functions I have use this function in my database. Is there any way I can find out in which procedure or function I am using this function so I can change the query there as well so it might not affect the result?

Function name is `fnIsOffDay`.

Comment: Right-click on the function in SSMS object explorer and select view dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a script from the database and search through content for the function name. Right click on the database > Tasks > Generate scripts > Next > Select specific database objects > Choose stored procedures and user defined functions > Next > Save to new query window > Next > Finish.

Comment: This tells the OP how to get the definition of their functions, not how many *other* objects reference a specific object.

Comment: Larnu: are you not looking at the question? He is asking to know in how many stored procs and functions the function 'fnIsOffDay' is being called.